# Tricky sort of a multi-index dataframe

Tags: sorting, pandas

After spending some time jumping through the pandas docs and searching questions here, I can't figure out how to accomplish the following:

Sort the "Ax" blocks by the value determined by index "B0" and column "G".

An example output is given below (I manually sorted the blocks for the desired result). Note that I don't want the order of the "Bx" indices to be changed.

Input:

```
In [153]: dfmi
Out[153]: 
        R   G   B
A0 B0   0   7   2
   B1   3  16   5
   B2   6  10   8
A1 B0   9  22  11
   B1  12  19  14
   B2  15  25  17
A2 B0  18  13  20
   B1  21   1  23
   B2  24   4  26
```

Desired result:

```
In [153]: dfmi
Out[153]: 
        R   G   B
A0 B0   0   7   2
   B1   3  16   5
   B2   6  10   8
A2 B0  18  13  20
   B1  21   1  23
   B2  24   4  26
A1 B0   9  22  11
   B1  12  19  14
   B2  15  25  17
```

What I have attempted so far is to extract an array corresponding to the values I am interested in,

```
In [154]: unordered_array = dfmi.loc[(slice(None), 'B0'),:]['G'].values
In [155]: unordered_array
Out[155]: array([ 7, 22, 13])
```

sort the array using numpy

```
In [157]: sort_order = np.argsort(unorder_array)
In [158]: sort_order
Out[158]: array([0, 2, 1])
```

and use the resulting order to sort the "A" blocks. I failed so far in this last step. You might notice my numpy background as I just started using pandas. I might be trying to solve the "wrong" problem here.

Comment: It's a bad idea to rearrange the order of the index values as this will mean that indexing will fail or it will be slow as they need to be sorted: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex

Comment: I read that and (more or less) understand it. What would be the right idiom to use, then? The "As" actually represent images (their file name actually), the "Bs" represent different surfaces from a color checker. It would be more convenient to me to work with data ordered by the illuminant under which they were taken rather than by file name (images were taken at random times under different illuminants). Do I understand correctly that I might be needing to add a new index, and reindex my dataframe to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EdChum mentioned, there may be consequences to re-sorting your index, but here would be a way.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
sort_order = df.loc[idx[:, 'B0'], 'G'].argsort().values
sort_order
# Out[21]: array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int64)

label_order = df.index.levels[0].take(sort_order)
label_order
# Out[25]: Index(['A0', 'A2', 'A1'], dtype='object')

df.reindex(index=label_order, level=0)
# Out[26]
        R   G   B
A0 B0   0   7   2
   B1   3  16   5
   B2   6  10   8
A2 B0  18  13  20
   B1  21   1  23
   B2  24   4  26
A1 B0   9  22  11
   B1  12  19  14
   B2  15  25  17
```

Comment: I am marking this answer not only for addressing my initial request, which it does nicely, but also for hinting a (probably) better way of achieving it. I refer to the take() method, which I somehow overlooked in the docs.